# How can I find the execution branch for a YAML pipeline via the Azure DevOps API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

When you setup a pipeline based on a yaml file it makes you select the branch if its not in main.

[Screen grab of azuredevops branch selection of yaml editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PwAz.png)

Is there anyway to find this execution branch via the API?

I've been able to loop through each branch of a pipeline and attempt to retrieve the yaml file but this is rather time consuming for the number of pipelines and branches I'm working with

Comment: You should know where you are creating the pipeline. If you don't know that. How do you expect us to know that. Enlighten me please, if I have misunderstood your question

Comment: Can you explain or show how you're currently looping through each branch?  You can get the pipeline definitions through and API, but I'm assuming you're already doing that.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0

Answer (score -1):

Your main goal is not clear in your question )) However, if you want just to check yaml in your branches, you may use Git Rest API: [Items - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP).

use the following parameters:

- versionDescriptor.versionType - branch
- versionDescriptor.version - {name of branch}
- scopePath - {path to your yaml folder}

Comment: If a question isn't clear, don't guess -- request clarification by posting a comment.